# How to configure jenkins to upload build artifact to nexus?

Tags: jenkins, build, continuous-integration, nexus

I have jenkins jobs that builds ios and android app and i want jenkins to upload those artifact to nexus after build is done.Is there any way to do it? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are building the apps with Maven or Gradle or whatever (esp. the Android ones) a simple mvn deploy or gradle uploadArchives will do the trick. Same applies if you build the ios app with one of these tools.

In most other cases you can always do normal upload via the REST API.

Examples for the Maven and Gradle setup are in the [eval guide](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/eval.html) and [the examples to the Nexus book](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples).

Comment: 1. We are a MS shop so unlike people can accept Maven approach. 2. We control Nexus in a way that only build users can do the upload. How can I secure the build user's password using REST API?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Nexus Artifact Uploader](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Nexus+Artifact+Uploader) Plugin, and set up a new job where you set a build step to **Copy artifacts form another project**, and a step to **Upload artifact to Nexus**

Comment: Need not to keep the artifacts in 2 locations, so we can upload artifacts generated from previous steps in the same job.